# How to post multiselect selected options as one param in url - Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect) and need to submit form with selected options.

However on form submit, url gets like this `....&sites=1&sites=2&sites=3` while I need it to be `...&sites=1,2,3`

Here is my code:

```
<select id="sites" name="sites" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
    <option value="3">Site 3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('button[type=submit]').click(function () {

      var text = $('#sites').val()
      //I have the list in `text` as 1,2,3 which need to in url
      //do the rest and continue submit
```

How can I POST these selected values in url (i.e `url/sites=1,2,3` instead of `url/sites=1&sites=2&sites=3`)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can replace all that code with just `$('#sites').val()`. That will provide a comma-delimited string containing the selected values. I'm not sure the exact point of your question though, as the code you have now, while verbose, would work as you require.

Comment: ok, let me try. but how to post that in url as sites=1,2,3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it done by using a hidden field.

```
var text = $('#sites').val();
$('#sites_hidded').val(text);
```

with html (removed name attr from select so it will not submit with form)

```
<select id="sites" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
    <option value="3">Site 3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="sites" id="sites_hidden">
```

Answer (score 8):

You may rename select to ***sites[]***

```
<select id="sites" name="sites[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Site 1</option>
    <option value="2">Site 2</option>
    <option value="3">Site 3</option>
</select>
```

This is will be send to server by submit without any js one variable ***sites*** as array with multi selected options.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: For whatever reason this solution produces this kind of URL:
`/?sites%5B%5D=2&sites%5B%5D=3`
This translates to `/?sites[]=2&sites[]=3`

That is wrong. It should be `/?sites[]=2,3`
Something off here :)